# Showering on Shabbat and removing the chill.

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, showering-bathing

1)If I live in an apartment complex, and I hold cold showers are okay on shabbos. Can I slightly open the hot water faucet in order to remove the chill of the cold water?

2)Since the apartment buildings hot water tank is so large, wouldn't it be a safek if I would be the one to cause the water to reboil?

3) and even if I do cause it to reboil, wouldn't it just be gramma? Do sefardi poskim permit this?

Comment: Re: No. 2: Even if the hot water tank was off, if the water in it was sufficiently hot, by opening the hot water faucet you'd be letting some cold water into the tank that would definitely be heated by the hot water already there. I don't see the _Safeq_ there. Regarding the opinion of Sephardic _Posqim_ on washing with hot water, if you have the Hebrew for it, see R. Ovadia Yosef's opinion [here](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/FrenchDisplayRead.asp?readID=744) and [here](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/DisplayRead.asp?readID=324).

Comment: The tzomet institute of technology makes water heaters designed to deal with these problems

Comment: @DavidFeigen Take into account that the [Zomet water heater](http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=250&ArticleID=103) deals with these problems by making sure the water doesn't rise above 40 degrees Celsius, and checking periodically (instead of automatically) to warm it up again to that temperature. Also note that the article I linked to mentions using that water for washing hands, face and even bathing a baby but does not mention using it for bathing one's self in.

Answer (score 2):

According to Dovid Ribiat in his book "39 Melocho", apparently the issues surrounding this are sufficiently complex that you might need to talk to a rav about this-- this exact issue is mentioned. I would imagine that the key element is how many apartments the hot-water heater services.